# How do I verify that 2 mock methods are called with same reference?

Tags: c++, googlemock

Suppose I am testing a method that declares some internal variable (on stack). The variable is passed by reference to one object (method `setupFoo()`) to fill it with the right values, then passed by reference to another object (method `useFoo()`) to use the values.

How can I write my EXPECT_CALLs and matchers to verify that both calls to the mocked methods get the **same** reference? Right now I simply use `_` to ignore the references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do something like:

```
const void* ref = nullptr;
EXPECT_CALL(mock, setupFoo(_)).WillOnce(Invoke([&](const auto& ptr) { ref = &ptr;}));
EXPECT_CALL(mock, useFoo(_)).WillOnce(Invoke([&](auto& ptr) { EXPECT_EQ(ref, &ptr);}));
```

Comment: what do you think about my alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

Another option, using `Truly()` call:

```
template <class T>
struct SameReference {
    const T **ptr;
    SameReference(const T **pointer) : ptr(pointer){}
    bool operator()(const T &ref) const {
        if (*ptr == nullptr) *ptr = &ref;
        return *ptr == &ref;
    }
};

template <class T>  SameReference<T> sameReference(T *&ptr){return SameReference<T>(&ptr);}
```

...

```
const ErrorInfo *asThis = nullptr;
EXPECT_CALL(errorUtils, setupError(Truly(sameReference(asThis))));
EXPECT_CALL(responseCreator, createException(Truly(sameReference(asThis))));
```

Comment: Notice that order of calls is not checked (`Sequence` might resolve that).